# Align submenu down

Tags: css, hover, submenu, dropdown

So I'm making a minor button and navigation kit in terms of learning more HTML and CSS responsiveness. Navigation is my weak point and I've come to my first problem that I can't get my head around.

https://jsfiddle.net/ku0wezws/3

If you scroll to the bottom of the CSS, you'll find the `subnav implementation` and what I'm trying to achieve is to align all the content in the center when you hover over `About`. You'll notice that it has just aligned one after the other side by side. My aim is to center all of that normally, going all the way down. Like this: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp

Am I being really stupid? I think I am. What should I adjust in the CSS to make this happen?

Thank you.

Edit:

Edited the JSFiddle

Comment: Please edit your code and make it just enough to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Just clear your float on `.jkit-nav-inverse ul li ul li{
  clear: both;
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to prevent the `li` items of that submenu to float next to each other:

```
.jkit-subnav li {
      float:none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yhkuv138/

Answer (score 0):

Just clear the `float` from `.jkit-nav-inverse ul li ul li`.

Add below code to the end of your CSS.

```
.jkit-nav-inverse ul li ul li{
  clear: both;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ku0wezws/2/)